# Get value from returnActivity when backpressed android

Tags: android, onactivityresult, onbackpressed

I have 2 activities in my Android application, `Activity1` and `Activity2`.

I want to display the data retrieved from a String in `Activity2` and this string value set text in Activity 1 textview when back is pressed from Activity2.

Please anyone give the solution for this problem,thanks in advance.

**Activity 2**: here I pass the string value to Activity 1 when I back press the Activity 2 this will be retrieved to Activity 1.

```
  public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     NoolDataBaseHelper db = new   NoolDataBaseHelper(NoolDashboardDetailPage.this);
    int strtext = db.getProfilesCount();
    db.close();
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("Obj", strtext+"");
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
    if (isclose) {

        finish();

    } 
else
 {
        if (!isplays) {
            inflateLoginlayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            topview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            isplays = true;
            //edtnames.getText().clear();

        }
 else
 {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

}
```

**Activity1**: here i retreive the string from Activity 2 and set the string     value to my textview

```
@Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if (requestCode == 1) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        String sSuName = data.getStringExtra("Obj");
        txtfavouratecount.setText(sSuName);
    } else if (resultCode == 0) {
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should follow this structure
In Activity 1

```
Intent intent=new Intent(Activity1.this,Activity2.class);  
startActivityForResult(intent, 2);// Activity is started with requestCode 2  

 @Override  
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);  
  // check the request code here is 2  
  if(requestCode==2){  
        if(resultCode == 3){ // check the result code
            String message=data.getStringExtra("MESSAGE");   
            // set text for your textview      
            textView1.setText(message); 
        }   
  }
```

}

In Activity 2

```
public void onBackPressed() {
  String message = "abc";
  Intent intent=new Intent();  
  intent.putExtra("MESSAGE",message);  
  setResult(3,intent); // 3 is result code
  super.onBackPressed(); 
}
```

Hope this help